# Problems Accessing Google Sheets Addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I created a google sheets addon that pulls some information from gmail and displays it in a specific format on a worksheet. This addon is to be used only by my account so I've set it as unlisted in the webstore. I've published this addon to google and paid my $5. It looks like everything got accepted just fine and when I see the definition of the addon on the store it says: Published / GAM: Pending  under Status.

Initially, when I clicked on the Addon's Name in the Developer Dashboard I was able to see what the Addon would look like in the store and there was a link to install the addon for free. When I would click this link I would get taken to an empty google sheet and then after a few seconds I would get a pop-up that would say "Add-on not found. Try again, or check back later." I did as suggested and tried several times later with no luck. Then after a while when I now visit the chrome developer dashboard and I click the addon's Name I get taken to the G-Suite Market place page not the addon's page. I tried replushing the addon but still got the same results.

Does it take hours for google to process unlisted addons? Is there something that I a missing? I read something about google store migrating to G suite market place, is this part of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the Add-ons menu is choosen in a Google spreadsheet, and the "Get add-ons" menu item is clicked, the GSuite Marketplace now opens by default.

The changes that you have experienced *are* because of the migration of add-ons from the Chrome Web Store to the GSuite Marketplace.

It *is* still possible to navigate to your listing in the Chrome Web Store, but you can't do that through the ***old*** Chrome Web Store developer dashboard.  You need to go to the new Developer Dashboard.  The problem is, that even though you can see the unlisted add-on listing in the Chrome Web Store, it can't be installed.

[New Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/devconsole/)

In the status column you will see a Published-Unlisted status for your add-on.

If you don't use the ***new*** Chrome Web Store developer dashboard, then you may not be able to find your listing at all for add-on published as unlisted.

Comment: Alan, thanks for your reply. It looks like I am able to access the new chrome developer dashboard and I do see my addon with a status of 'Published-Unlisted'. When its name on the list I am taken to the page that shows the details of the addon and there is a link that says "View in Chrome Web Store". I can follow this link to see the addon's listing in the webstore (yay!) but the button that says "Add to Chrome" is disabled. How can I actually add this addon to my google sheets?

Comment: It seems that an add-on can't be installed from the Chrome Web Store anymore.  That's not good.  I have a user who is using an add-on of mine, and I don't want to publish the add-on publicly.  The add-on is just for their company.  If you do publish the add-on publicly, it will probably never show up in the add-on store unless someone searches for it directly.  But then you'd need to check the user email to make sure that no one else installs it.  Google probably wants people using free accounts to pay for a G Suite account.  If you have a G Suite account then you can publish just to domain.

Comment: It seems like bad timing on my part I suppose then. What I am trying to achieve is to have a script running on my spreadsheet without it asking me to authorize it each time. I currently have this script as part of the spreadsheet. The problem is that this spreadsheet will get copied over and over again an infinite number of times and each time it does and the script that access gmail runs it asks to be authorized. 

It was suggested that I should use an addon instead to prevent this from happening but it looks like this is not longer an option. Is there any way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: There are two other options to use one central code file for many documents.  One is a library.  But I'm not sure if it's possible to only authorize the library once.  The other option would be to have a stand alone web app, that you pass variable values to, and the web app does all the work.  You'd need to pass the spreadsheet ID to the Web App so that the web app could work on the spreadsheet that called the web app.  I'd probably go with the web app.  The Web App will need to be called with `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url of published web app, options)`  You'd still need to authorize an ext request.

Comment: Thank-you for all your help!